# Linked List Intuition

Tags: java, linked-list

```
public void printList( ){
    Node<E> p ;
    System.out.printf( ” [ ” ) ;
    for ( p=head.next ; p != null ; p=p.next )
        System.out.print( p.element ) ;
    System.out.printf( ” ] ” ) ;
}

public void addLast (E e){
    Node<E> p = head;   // <--- data type Node<E>, var name = p, but what is head type?
    while ( p.next != null )
        p = p.next ;
    p.next = new Node<E>(e , null ) ;
}
```

Generics Example:

```
public class Box {
private Object object;

public void set(Object object) { this.object = object; }
public Object get() { return object; }
```

}

Using Generics:

```
// T stands for "Type"
public class Box<T> {
    private T t; 

    public void set(T t) { 
        this.t = t;
    }
    public T get() { 
        return t;
    }
}
```

I have a general idea of how linked list work intuitively however I can't see it in code.

I know you have the element and a reference to the next node. In the code above, how does the "." operator work as it traverses through the list until null is reached?

I believe 'next' is a reference variable. when it does p=p.next, how does it work in code/computer?

On a unrelated note, node ? instead of node(E)? difference? In the example above, it seems 'object' was replaced by 't', i can't see the advantage. ;S

Any help is really appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might help to think of a LinkedList as a List of linked Nodes. Where each Node will hold a reference to the next Node (if one exists). I'm not sure if it will help, but when I had to do this assignment in School I found that looking through the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) and trying to use it very helpful.

With Generics Node will be a Node of type Object Where Node will be a Node of a specific type. For example, LinkedList will hold Strings. [This](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html), might help to get a better understanding of how generics work.

Here is a simple example of using generics:

```
Class Box<E>{
    private E variable;

    public E get(){
        return variable;
    }

    public void set(E variable){
        this.variable=variable;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Box<String> example=new Box<String>();
        example.set("test");
        System.out.println(example.get());

        Box<Integer> example2=new Box<Integer>();
        example2.set(1);
        //example2.set("test");will not work because it is types as an Integer
        System.out.println(example2.get()+1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Still dont grasp the concepts of generics... care to elaborate a bit more? thanks.

Comment: I hate to ask something so vague, but is there something specific about them that you are having difficulty with? Or is it just the general concept?

Comment: I just edited my answer to give an example of how you can use generics.

Comment: so the class 'example' is made generic to accept any primitive type variables coming in?

Makes sense.

Comment: Yes, except those are not primitive types. String and Integer (not int) are Objects. You could use the above code and have it take in any Object.

Comment: Also, the type is fixed, I'll add a method to set a variable to show you what I mean.

Comment: last question, and thanks for being patient,
Example<String> example=new Example<String>("test"); 
this creates new object named example, and passes "test" into the constructor which takes the value of "test" as variable? you mentioned "string" is the object, but the oject name is 'example'. Sorry if thats confusing.

Comment: ok, so the edit makes a bit more sense, set is defined somewhere?

Comment: Java is a statically typed language, generics is kind of like a way of getting around some of that. It might help to think about why they are useful to help get a better understanding of them. Without generics, You would have to create a different implementation of the above class for every Object type. You would need to create different versions of a LinkList for String, Integer, any Object you create yourself, etc. (I hope that helps)

Comment: Thanks John, i'd give you a thumbs up but it wont let me. not enough rep.

Comment: Dont worry about it, generics is a tough concept

Answer (score 0):

In the code above, as long as `head.next` is not equal to null p will be set to the next "link" in the list. This will continue on. `p.next` returns a reference to the next link which is then set to p. This reference chain will continue on.

`Node<E>` is a generic type which allows the user of the class to pass a type for the node to contain. This allows greater type safety than simply using casts.

Comment: is 'next' defined as a variable? its not above, should it be??

Comment: next could be a variable or a method, but in either case it is returning a reference to the next "link" in the chain. This is then set to p and the cycle repeats

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `Node` class is of the below kind:

```
class Node<T>{
    Node<T> next;
    T element;
}
```

Now any reference of the 'Node' class has an access to it's two properties. And the `.` operator is used to access the properties.

When you set `p = p.next`, it is just a movement of pointers internally.

Comment: ahhh, thanks so 'next' must be defined in the class node? and object p has variables it can use from its parent class? which would be class Node<T> you have defined above.?